# How to install LLVMpipe?

Tags: installation, drivers, xorg, opengl, openchrome

I hear about the LLVMpipe gallium 3d state tracker that is said to be faster than software renderer. But I cannot find a good instruction from a to z that tell me how to install it. So here I am, asking you all how to install/compile LLVMpipe and use it as default OpenGL renderer. I'm using a desktop with only a VIA IGP using the openchrome driver which is not really great with opengl.

Comment: I also have not seen a direct way to test this out, is LLVMpipe VERY experimental?

Comment: ... I may be wrong but it looks like it is included in the xorg ppa, .. might also be in by now, but not using gallium so can't check.  God I can't wait for wayland.... been so many years of this mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to try llvmpipe, depending on how much work you want to do and if it *must* be on Ubuntu.

Most people are testing in a virtual machine (Virtualbox or KVM). Gnome-shell in Virtualbox , VM = Ubuntu precise (12.04) using the ppa below.

[image: gnome-shell]

The first option is to try it on Fedora 17 Alpha (it is installed and configured by default)

Here is a screen shot of gnome-shell running on my gma500 in Fedora 17 aplha

[image: gma500]

Your second option is to try this ppa:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

It does not yet automatically start when you log in from lightdm, but it is in progress.

See this forms discussion for further information http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11713944

I am posting the forums thread as it is a work in progress and that link will likely continue to be helpful.

Your third option would be to compile it from source. There are specific instructing for how to do so here: http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

See this discussion as well: http://wootangent.net/2011/11/on-unity2d-and-llvmpipe-and-the-differing-approaches-of-fedora-and-ubuntu/